# Linq - get elements that are top in hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have the following data:

[image]

I need to get the top elements in the tree data structure. All the rows where the `AncestorId` equals `DescendantId` are parents but I need first to get the top parents. For example:

```
2 and 34
```

Becuase element with `ID 2` just exist once in the `descendantid` column, also for element with `ID 34`.

Then I have to get the children below `ID 2` and `ID 34` and so on so I can start building my tree structure.

This is how the table data should look line in a visual tree:

[image]

Right now I have the following Linq statement to get the parents nodes:

```
// get parent nodes
var parentNodes = data.Where(i => i.AncestorId == i.DescedantId ).ToList();
```

How can I get in a linq query the Top parents, and then how to get the children, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
To get the Top parents (i.e. they only appear once in Descendant Id), you can do the following

```
var parentNodes = data
    .Where(i => i.AncestorId == i.DescedantId &&
                (data.Count(d => d.DescedantId == i.DescedantId) == 1))
    .ToList();
```

And to get the children of a parent:

```
var allChildren = data.Except(parentNodes);
var someParent = parentNodes.First();
var someParentsChildren = 
    allChildren.Where(i => i.AncestorId == someParent.DescendantId)
```

Comment: Top parents mean that in a tree structure are the very top elements. The ID 2 and ID 34 are the top most nodes. I need to get those, and then on other query the child, and so on.

Comment: Now I can see, let me try

Comment: How can I have a loop function so I can check all depth instead of going one by one and checking if has children, etc.? Btw. it worked the parentNodes

Comment: You could write a function to `GetChildren` that takes a `Parent`, using the sample code above to get the children of a parent, and call it recursively. What data structure are you using to store the information?

Comment: Let me create a new question and I give you the link with that information. First let me check the answer :) Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the link of new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008848/linq-how-to-loop-a-tree-data-structure-to-build-a-tree-style-object