# Linq - how to loop a tree data structure to build a tree style object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have the following SQL table data:

[image]

The visual tree should look something like this:

[image]

To get the very top nodes I'm using:

```
var parentNodes = data
    .Where(i => i.AncestorId == i.DescedantId &&
                (data.Count(d => d.DescedantId == i.DescedantId) == 1))
    .ToList();
```

Any clue on how to build a function that would loop trough the structure and then build the tree style object?

My tree style object classes are:

```
public class ProfitCenterRoot
{
    public List<ProfitCenterItem> Data { get; set; }
}

public class ProfitCenterItem
{
    public int AncestorId { get; set; } 
    public int DescendantId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Leaf { get; set; }

    // These are the child items
    public List<ProfitCenterItem> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `recusrive method` here.

Comment: how can I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to add children to each parent. But first, I would add a default constructor to your classes to initialize the Data lists:

```
public class ProfitCenterRoot
{
    public List<ProfitCenterItem> Data { get; set; }

    public ProfitCenterRoot()
    {
        Data = new List<ProfitCenterItem>();
    }
}

public class ProfitCenterItem
{
    // Existing properties here

    public ProfitCenterItem()
    {
        Data = new List<ProfitCenterItem>();
    }
}
```

Then you can create a simple method that takes in a Parent and a list of all children, recursively add children to each child of the parent, and then add the children to the parent:

```
public static void AddChildren(ProfitCenterItem parent, 
    IEnumerable<ProfitCenterItem> allChildren )
{
    var children = allChildren
        .Where(child =>
               child.AncestorId == parent.DescendantId &&
               child.AncestorId != child.DescendantId)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        AddChildren(child, allChildren.Except(children));
        parent.Data.Add(child);
    }
}
```

So to populate your objects, you could then do:

```
var parentNodes = data
    .Where(i => i.AncestorId == i.DescendantId &&
                (data.Count(d => d.DescendantId == i.DescendantId) == 1))
    .ToList();

var root = new ProfitCenterRoot();

foreach (var parentNode in parentNodes)
{
    AddChildren(parentNode, data.Except(parentNodes));
    root.Data.Add(parentNode);
}
```

Comment: Update: I made a slight perf improvement to the `AddChildren` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an even easier way to build the tree.

First up though, it seems odd to have the properties `AncestorId` & `DescendantId` for each node, so I simplified the structure to just `Id` like this:

```
public class ProfitCenterItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public List<ProfitCenterItem> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now it becomes easy.

The nodes that are actually relevant are those where `AncestorId != DescendantId` so we get those:

```
var nonSelf =
    data
        .Where(x => x.AncestorId != x.DescendantId)
        .ToArray();
```

Now the parent nodes are simply those ids that appear on the left but don't appear on the right. Like this:

```
var parentNodes =
    Enumerable
        .Except(
            nonSelf.Select(x => x.AncestorId),
            nonSelf.Select(x => x.DescendantId));
```

Now to build the tree we create a lookup for the children:

```
var lookup = nonSelf.ToLookup(x => x.AncestorId, x => x.DescendantId);
```

Here's the trickiest part - a recursive build function for traversing the lookup to build all the nodes:

```
Func<int, ProfitCenterItem> build = null;
build = n =>
    new ProfitCenterItem()
    {
        Id = n,
        Data = lookup[n].Select(x => build(x)).ToList()
    };
```

Finally we just need to create the root node and call `build` to create the parent nodes:

```
var root = new ProfitCenterRoot()
{
    Data = parentNodes.Select(x => build(x)).ToList()
};
```

Here's the result I get:

[image: results]